# useLocation Hook returns wrong path

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, cross-platform, progressive-web-apps

I built an Ionic-React App that can scan a QR-Code and connect to a Device based on that. I use the `useLocation()` and `useHistory()` Hooks to route through my App.

I pass some Data like that:

```
    const Home: React.FC = () => {

  let history = useHistory()

  const startScan = async () => {
//Some Barcode Logic
 history.replace("/gatherData", {scan: result.content})
    }};
```

and recieve it using:

```
const GatherData: React.FC = () => {

    let history = useHistory();
    let location = useLocation();

    useIonViewWillEnter(() => {
        console.log(location);
    });
```

I did this, as usual and it seemed to be working quite nicely. But now, somehow, the `useLocation()` Hook does not recognize the history changing anymore. Although I get routed to the next page, the `useLocation()` returns an old path:

```
{pathname: '/home', ... state: undefined, key: 'bdwus9'}
```

I did try to recode the thing but that didn't solve the issue. Also trying to catch bugs in the `HomeFC` and in the `GatherDataFC` didn't help. It would be great if anyone had a solution to the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useIonViewWillEnter` currently gets an obsolete state because it's cached, just like many other hooks. To fix this, you need to explicitly tell it that its dependency location was changed.

```
useIonViewWillEnter(() => {
    console.log(location);
}, [location]/*depdendency array*/);
```

Comment: Thanks man, you saved my App-Meeting in 2,5 hours...